# The number of occurrences of substrings within a string in O(N)

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, aho-corasick

I was wondering how to count the number of occurences of each needle in a haystack in linear time. I thought I would use Aho-Corasick algorithm but I don't want  time complexity to depend on the number of occurences of the needles.

Comment: Is the substring fixed? That is, do you need to count the number of times a fixed string S occurs in a fixed string T?

Comment: That was my mistake, it was meant for multiple needles, now it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use [*Rabin–Karp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) if you want to search for a set of strings and don't like to depend on the number of occurrences. Its average/best case running time is `O(n + m)`, but its worst-case time is O(nm), where `n` is length of text and `m` is combined length of search patterns.

If you want to search only one string you could use [*Knuth–Morris–Pratt*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) with complexity `O(n + k)`, where `n` is length of text and `k` is length of search pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the total number of occurrences (and you don't care about the positions themselves), you can use Aho-Corasick efficiently. Let's assume that we are currently in the node `v`. How many substrings end in the current position. I claim that it's exactly the number of terminal nodes reachable from `v` by suffix links. But suffix links form a tree. Thus, we need to count the number of terminal vertices on the path from `v` to the root in the tree formed by suffix links. We can do it in `O(1)` time with linear preprocessing (for instance, one can build this tree explicitly and compute the sum on the path from root to any vertex in linear time using one depth-first search). We can also process the vertices in right order (for instance, in increasing order of height) and do something like `sum[v] += sum[suffix_link(v)]`. In that case, we don't even need to actually build this tree.

This algorithm clearly works in linear time in the size of input (we build the Aho-Corasick automaton and compute the sum on " suffix link paths"in linear time, and then we use the automaton as we would normally do).

Comment: I believe your approach also works for finding the positions of the occurences. You can make an Euler tour in the suffix link tree and perform square root decomposition. This way, you will get the answer in O(n * sqrt n).